# How to split large video based on list of sentences using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of sentences, and speakers which saying these sentences front of camera, I want to split the video based on the sentences using python. I wondering is it possible to do this using python?

Comment: Do you have a time tag for those sentences ?

Comment: Or a subtitle file ?

Comment: It is possible, but questions as generic as this one are not meant for StackOverflow. Consider doing some research on the topic first and coming back with code that supports your attempts to complete this task. From there, we can help point out where you went wrong and make suggestions of new things to try.

Comment: Thanks Agile_Eagle for reply. Unfortunately I do not have timing and subtitle. I have long videos and list of sentences